# Terraform: what does AssumeRole: Service: ec2 do?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

What exactly does this AWS role do?

The most relevant bits seem to be: 
`"Action": "sts:AssumeRole",` and 
`"Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"`

The full role is here:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "test_role" {
  name = "test_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

From: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role.html

Comment: `The policy that grants an entity permission to assume the role.` In this case an `entity` needs to be an EC2-Instance: `ec2.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 96, accepted):

To understand the meaning of this it is necessary to understand some details of how IAM Roles work.

An IAM role is similar to a *user* in its structure, but rather than it being accessed by a fixed set of credentials it is instead used by *assuming* the role, which means to request and obtain temporary API credentials that allow taking action with the privileges that are granted to the role.

[The `sts:AssumeRole` action](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) is the means by which such temporary credentials are obtained. To use it, a user or application calls this API using some already-obtained credentials, such as a user's fixed access key, and it returns (if permitted) a new set of credentials to act as the role. This is the mechanism by which AWS services can call into other AWS services on your behalf, by which IAM Instance Profiles work in EC2, and by which a user can temporarily switch access level or accounts within the AWS console.

The *assume role policy* determines which *principals* (users, other roles, AWS services) are permitted to call `sts:AssumeRole` for this role. In this example, the EC2 service itself is given access, which means that EC2 is able to take actions on your behalf using this role.

---

This role resource *alone* is not useful, since it doesn't have any IAM policies associated and thus does not grant any access. Thus an `aws_iam_role` resource will always be accompanied by at least one other resource to specify its access permissions. There are several ways to do this:

- Use [`aws_iam_role_policy`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role_policy.html) to attach a policy directly to the role. In this case, the policy will describe a set of AWS actions the role is permitted to execute, and optionally other constraints.
- Use [`aws_iam_policy`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_policy.html) to create a *standalone* policy, and then use [`aws_iam_policy_attachment`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_policy_attachment.html) to associate that policy with one or more roles, users, and groups. This approach is useful if you wish to attach a single policy to multiple roles and/or users.
- Use service-specific mechanisms to attach policies at the service level. This is a different way to approach the problem, where rather than attaching the policy to the role, it is instead attached to the object whose access is being controlled. The mechanism for doing this varies by service, but for example the `policy` attribute on [`aws_s3_bucket`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket.html) sets bucket-specific policies; the `Principal` element in the policy document can be used to specify which principals (e.g. roles) can take certain actions.

IAM is a flexible system that supports several different approaches to access control. Which approach is right for you will depend largely on how your organization approaches security and access control concerns: managing policies from the role perspective, with `aws_iam_role_policy` and `aws_iam_policy_attachment`, is usually appropriate for organizations that have a centralized security team that oversees access throughout an account, while service-specific policies delegate the access control decisions to the person or team responsible for each separate object. Both approaches can be combined, as part of a *defense in depth* strategy, such as using role- and user-level policies for "border" access controls (controlling access from *outside*) and service-level policies for internal access controls (controlling interactions between objects within your account).

---

More details on roles can be found in the AWS IAM guide [*IAM Roles*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html). See also [*Access Management*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access.html), which covers the general concepts of access control within IAM.

Comment: I thought I won't read this long one, but this is well written. +10

Comment: +1 and wanted to add - this may be naive and wrong, but I often think of a Role as a bucket for policies. In that sense, a Role is actually closer to a Group than a User - at least in terms of how I personally believe permissions should be assigned to individual users. A main difference between a Group and a Role is, whereas a Group can be assigned to a User, a Role can be assigned to things that aren't Users. So for example, an EC2 instance can have permissions to Dynamo by virtue of a Role with the correct Policy applied.

Comment: That's a good analogy, @JohnDibling! I think the intended connotation of the noun "role" is like the separation between a particular human and a job role that human has. I'm Martin Atkins everywhere, but in the context of my employer I'm a sysadmin, in the context of my dentist I'm a patient, etc. In many settings, what I'm allowed to do is decided by what role I'm playing in that context, not by who I am as an individual. "Roles" in an access control system express that indirection.

Comment: With that said then, we could understand the AssumeRole policy as like deciding who is allowed to play the role of "dental hygienist" at the dentist's office. There are several people who are equally allowed to do that, but I can't just show up there and start offering to clean people's teeth, because my "user" is not permitted to assume the role of "dental hygienist". ;)

Comment: I'm going to start using that analogy, @MartinAtkins.