# Correct terraform syntax for adding permissions to AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform

I'm learning Terraform and I'm trying to get the correct syntax to specify the IAM role permissions for it. I want these capabailities:

1. Lambda can be invoked from an API Gateway that I also create in Terraform
2. Lambda can write to Cloudwatch logs

I have the following which allows the API gateway to invoke the Lambda:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "my_lambda_execution_role" {
  name = "my_lambda_execution_role"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [ 
          "lambda.amazonaws.com",
          "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

I have seen the snippet below allows the Lambda to write to CloudWatch. I'm trying to combine these snippets to get all of the permissions but I can't get it right. What is the correct syntax to give all of these permissions to the role?

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                 "logs:CreateLogStream",
                 "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role_policy_attachment.html

You need to create the policy and then attach it to your role.   The link above includes a more complete example than on the iam role page.

Answer (score 3):

In [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623056/terraform-what-does-assumerole-service-ec2-do/44658378#44658378) I wrote up some background information on how IAM roles work and what an "assume role policy" is. I'm going to assume that background information in this answer.

The policy you've given in your `assume_role_policy` argument in the `resource "aws_iam_role" "my_lambda_execution_role"` block is the policy governing which users and services are allowed to "assume" this role. In this case, you are allowing AWS Lambda and Amazon API Gateway to make requests using the privileges granted by this role.

However, by default the role doesn't grant any privileges at all. To address that, we need to attach one or more access policies to the role. The other policy JSON you shared here is an access policy, and to associate it with the role we need to use the `aws_iam_role_policy` resource type:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "logs" {
  name   = "lambda-logs"
  role   = aws_iam_role.my_lambda_execution_role.name
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": [
          "logs:CreateLogGroup",
          "logs:CreateLogStream",
          "logs:PutLogEvents",
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

Usually Terraform automatically infers dependencies between `resource` blocks by noticing references like the `aws_iam_role.my_lambda_execution_role` expression in the above, and indeed in this case Terraform will determine automatically that it needs to complete the creation of the role before attempting to attach the policy to it.

However, Terraform *cannot* see automatically here that the policy attachment must complete before the policy itself is operable, and so when you refer to the role from your API Gateway and Lambda resources you must use `depends_on` to tell Terraform that the policy attachment must complete before the policy will become usable:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "example" {
  filename      = "${path.module}/example.zip"
  function_name = "example"
  role          = aws_iam_role.my_lambda_execution_role.arn
  handler       = "example"

  # (and any other configuration you need)

  # Make sure the role policy is attached before trying to use the role
  depends_on = [aws_iam_role_policy.logs]
}
```

If you don't use `depends_on` like this, there is a risk that the function will be created and executed before the role attachment is complete, and thus initial executions of your function could fail to write their logs. If your function is not executed immediately after it's created then this probably won't occur in practice, but it's good to include the `depends_on` to be thorough and to let a future human maintainer know that the role's access policy is *also* important for the functionality of the Lambda function.

Answer (score 2):

- IAM policy along with role.

```
# iam
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy" {
  statement {
    sid    = ""
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      identifiers = ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
      type        = "Service"
    }

    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_for_lambda" {
  name               = "iam_for_lambda"
  assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.policy.json}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "frontend_lambda_role_policy" {
  name   = "frontend-lambda-role-policy"
  role   = "${aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.id}"
  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.lambda_log_and_invoke_policy.json}"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "lambda_log_and_invoke_policy" {

  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    actions = [
      "logs:CreateLogGroup",
      "logs:CreateLogStream",
      "logs:PutLogEvents",
    ]

    resources = ["*"]

  }

  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    actions = ["lambda:InvokeFunction"]

    resources = ["arn:aws:lambda:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:function:*"]
  }

}
```

- Please find the complete terraform code at my [github](https://github.com/amittn/api-gateway-lambda)