# Error creating IAM Role: MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-iam

I am trying to create a Lambda role and attach it a policy to Allow all ElasticSearch cluster operations.

Below is the code -

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_iam" {
  name = "lambda_iam"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
            "Action": [
                "es:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }]
  }
EOF
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "developmentlambda" {
  filename      = "lambda_function.zip"
  function_name = "name"
  role          = "${aws_iam_role.lambda_iam.arn}"
  handler       = "exports.handler"

  source_code_hash = "${filebase64sha256("lambda_function.zip")}"

  runtime = "nodejs10.x"
}
```

I get the following error

```
Error creating IAM Role lambda_iam: MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource
```

The Terraform document regarding Resource says you can specify a "*" for ALL users.  The Principal field is not mandatory either so thats not the problem. 
I still changed it to be

```
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "es.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

But that said -

```
Error creating Lambda function: InvalidParameterValueException: The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda.
```

My lambda function definition is simple

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "development_lambda" {
  filename      = "dev_lambda_function.zip"
  function_name = "dev_lambda_function_name"
  role          = "${aws_iam_role.lambda_iam.arn}"
  handler       = "exports.test"

  source_code_hash = "${filebase64sha256("dev_lambda_function.zip")}"

  runtime = "nodejs10.x"
}
```

The lambda file itself has nothing in it but I do not know if that explains the error.

Is there something I am missing here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **assume role policy** is the role's *trust policy* (allowing the role to be assumed), not the role's *permissions policy* (what permissions the role grants to the assuming entity).

A Lambda execution role needs both types of policies.

The immediate error, that the *"role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda"* is occurring because it needs `"Principal": {"Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"}`, not `es.amazonaws.com` -- that goes in the permissions policy.  I don't use terraform, but it looks like that might be `resource "aws_iam_policy"` based on https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_function.html, which I assume is the reference you are working from.

Comment: Yes that is what I was working off of. What is the best way to allow ALL elasticsearch operation permissions to a lambda function ? That is what I am attempting to do here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wrote this answer a while back which might help with some additional context about how the "assume role policy" fits in to the bigger picture: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44658378/281848

Comment: Thanks @MartinAtkins. That helped.